How can I make the body of the snake follow the head without grid (unity, C#)
I'm remaking the game Snake to learn unity. Right now I'm stuck trying to make the body appear without ovelapping the head, basically atthaching the body to the head. Since all the tutorials use grid I can't think of a way to make this work. Here is the part of code related to this,
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using UnityEngine;

public class Snake : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    public float SVelocity;

    private List<Transform> _segments;

    public Transform segmentPreFab;
    public Vector3 SnakePosition;
    public Vector3 SnakeVelocity;
    public Vector3 SnakeHead;
    
    void Start()
    {
  
        _segments = new List<Transform>();
        _segments.Add(this.transform);
        myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.down * SVelocity;
     
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (myRigidbody.velocity == Vector2.up * SVelocity)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))

                myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.right * SVelocity;
                SnakePosition = myRigidbody.position;

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))

                myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.left * SVelocity;
                SnakePosition = myRigidbody.position;
        }

        if (myRigidbody.velocity == Vector2.down * SVelocity)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))

                myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.right * SVelocity;
                SnakePosition = myRigidbody.position;

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))

                myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.left * SVelocity;
                SnakePosition = myRigidbody.position;
        }

        if (myRigidbody.velocity == Vector2.right * SVelocity)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))

                myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.up * SVelocity;
                SnakePosition = myRigidbody.position;

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))

                myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.down * SVelocity;
                SnakePosition = myRigidbody.position;
        }

        if (myRigidbody.velocity == Vector2.left * SVelocity)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))

                myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.up * SVelocity;
                SnakePosition = myRigidbody.position;


            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))

                myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.down * SVelocity;
                SnakePosition = myRigidbody.position;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
       
        for (int i = _segments.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {

            _segments[i].position = _segments[i - 1].position;         

        }
        SnakeVelocity = myRigidbody.velocity;
    }
    private void Grow()
    {
        Transform segment = Instantiate(this.segmentPreFab);

        segment.position = _segments[_segments.Count - 1].position;

        _segments.Add(segment);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Food")
        {
            Grow();
        }
    }
    
}


I tried to adapt the code of a tutorial that is making the Snake the normal way (with a grid).

well Samyans doesnt use a grid, and you dont need to use a grid, you have the next piece move to the piece before it..like a chain being dragged across the floor

Since you aren't using a grid, you'll need to offset each segment from the previous by the segments size.  You cannot replace each position with the previous position (that would work on a grid, or if you always move by a full segment distance).  Simple solution is a hinge joint.  Also, do not do any physics work in Update, use FixedUpdate for physics and Update for input.
